# Why can points on the frontier of a convex set be identified through a minimization program.

Tags: optimization, reference-request, convex-analysis

Think, for instance, of a radius $1$ circle centered at $(1,1)$. If we want to identify the points on the southwestern quadrant of its circunference, one can solve the program

\begin{align}
\min &\quad w x +(1-w)y\\
\text{s.t.}&\quad\begin{cases}y\geq 1-\sqrt{1-(x-1)^2}\\x\geq 0\\y\geq 0\end{cases}
\end{align}

for $w\in(0,1)$, i.e, minimizing a convex combination of the components of the points belonging to the circle. For instance, $w=0$ results in $(1,0)$, $w=1$ in $(0,1)$ and $w=\frac{1}{4}$ in $(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}},1-\frac{3}{\sqrt{10}})$. It's easy to check that all these lie on the circumference.

My question is why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slopes of the tangent lines of a decreasing function are in one-to-one correspondence with the interval $(0,1)$. When you minimize the linear function $wx+(1-w)y$ for a fixed $w$, you are finding the point on the corresponding line that is tangent to the curve. For the northeastern quadrant of the circle, you would instead maximize (equivalently, minimize the negative). For the other two quadrants, you would negate the coefficient of either $x$ or $y$ in the linear objective function.

Comment: Is this a well known result or something I would need to provide a reference for. In case a reference is needed, can you offer one?

Comment: I've posted a follow up question on this. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3982261/why-can-points-on-the-frontier-of-a-convex-set-be-identified-through-a-minimizat